# Deduce the number of divisors, $d(n)$ is multiplicative and obtain a formula of $d(n)$ in terms of prime decomposition

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

I have been given a question which begins with me deducing $d(n)$ is multiplicative, I know $d(n)= \sum_{d|n} 1,$ and obtain a formula of $d(n)$ in terms of prime decomposition (once again I know is $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdot\cdot p_k^{a_k}$). I am aware that in order for a function to be multiplicative $f(nm)=f(n)f(m)$ where $(m,n)=1$ and f is non zero. The final part is deduce all positive integers $n$ for when;

$\bullet$  $d(n)$ is odd

$\bullet$ $d(n)= p_0,$ where $p_0$ is a fixed prime.

I have deduced $d(n)$ is multiplicative by letting $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdot\cdot p_k^{a_k}$, where

$$d(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdot\cdot p_k^{a_k})= (a_1+1)\cdot \cdot(a_k+1)=d(p_1^{a_1})\cdot d(p_2^{a_2})\cdot \cdot \cdot d(p_k^{a_k})$$

as we know the divisors of $n$ are $d=p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}\cdot\cdot p_k^{b_k} $ where eack $b_k$ gives a distinct divisor in the form of $(a_k+1)$. It is the next bit I do not understand.

Comment: Hi I have changed it the question you refered too does not include my two bullet points @dietrichburde

Comment: The bullet points also follow immediately form the formula. How can the product $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$ be odd, or be a prime number?

Comment: @DietrichBurde How would I find the integers though?

Comment: By the formula: $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$. Here you have determined the possible $a_i$; say, all zero, except for $a_1$. Then $n=p_1^{a_1}$, with $d(n)=(a_1+1)$ prime.

Comment: I am sorry i am still confused, to find all positive integers $n$ for which $d(n)$ is odd should I set $d(n)=2x+1$ where x is a natural number?

Comment: $d(n)$ is odd iff $(a_1+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$ is odd. For which $a_i$ does this happen?

Comment: only for $a_1$? as the rest will give an even when multiplied?

Comment: or would it be when $a_i$ is even, as odd $\times$ odd is an odd?